# Composer Debugging

Tags: laravel, debugging, composer-php

We try to install the following composer.json (.lock was deleted)

```
composer install -vvvvv
```

and get

Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #47)

In pass 47 it stay's forever.

Then we tried:

```
composer update -vvvv --lock
```

Which yields the error:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (installed at v5.5.40, required as 5.6.*) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - laravelcollective/html v5.5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40], illuminate/view[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40], illuminate/view[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.5.40].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html (installed at v5.5.4, required as ~5.0) -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.5.4].
```

Then we switched to a more loose composer.json, also we switched to PHP 7.2

```
{
    "name": "x/y",
    "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
    "php": "*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "*",
    "dsentker/phpinsights": "*",
    "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.6",
    "google/apiclient": "*",
    "jeroen-g/laravel-packager": "*",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "*",
    "paquettg/php-html-parser": "*",
    "rexxars/html-validator": "*",
    "sgrodzicki/pagespeed": "*",
    "spatie/laravel-analytics": "*",
    "zizaco/entrust": "*",
    "fideloper/proxy": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "*",
    "laracasts/generators": "*",
    "mockery/mockery": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ]
    },
    "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

With this in place we still get:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (installed at v5.5.40, required as 5.6.*) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - laravelcollective/html v5.5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40], illuminate/view[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40], illuminate/view[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.5.40].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html (installed at v5.5.4, required as *) -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.5.4].
```

How can we debug this properly? We a fishing in the dark a bit.

Comment: What is your intention to do? Install or update? If updating: Just a minor version or major version 5.5 -> 5.6.
What does it mean, `composer.lock` was deleted. By accident? Can you recover it from VCS?
PS: Verbose knows only three levels , not four or five as you have in your question. To debug use three (`-vvv`).